# LESS formatting

Tags: css, less, styling

I have been writing some LESS CSS code recently, and was wondering what the best way for format this would be.

Ideally i don't want to reproduce the button classes, and separate them from the input tags, unless that's the best way to go.

```
.button,
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"] {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 38px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 38px;
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box; 

    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        color: #333;
        border-color: #888;
        outline: 0;
    }

    &.button-primary {
        color: #FFF;
        background-color: #33C3F0;
        border-color: #33C3F0;

        &:hover,
        &:focus {
            color: #FFF;
            background-color: #1EAEDB;
            border-color: #1EAEDB;
        }
    }
}
```

I did initially think about doing them like this

```
.button,
button,
input {
    &:[type="submit"],
    &:[type="reset"],
    &:[type="button"] {}
```

However doing them like this would mean the button class would also have a type.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hade you tried with [`extend`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature)?

Comment: @Marwelln nice one, that looks like it could work well. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: @Marwelln looks to be working, can you post so i can mark as the answer? Not sure why people vote to close this cause this could help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by using the [`extend`](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) function in LESS.

```
button, .button {
    // styles
}

input {
    &[type="submit"], &[type="reset"], &[type="button"] {
        // All styles from .button will also be available here.
        &:extend(.button);
    }
}
```

Comment: It will add the `input` selectors to `button, .button`, but will not generate `input:hover`, `input.button-primary` etc. You need `&:extend(.button all);` to extend the nested selectors as well.

Comment: I have never used `extend` before so my code was just guess from a quick read at the documentation. Feel free to edit my post if you'd like @pawel.

Comment: Cheers guys, really helpful and has worked a treat. I looked at the link and it mentioned "all" as @pawel mentions. Thanks again